# Append value to end of time stamp

Tags: linux, append

I've got a csv file like below in a RHEL server & it has 9 million records. I need to create a new file with `.00000` added to the end of the date stamp.

```
Eg:2019-11-29 07:39:45.00000
```

sample Record

```
18045654,654897654645,2019-11-29 07:39:45,contra,tablu
```

So far I've tried below & it doesn't add anything

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3.'00000',$4}' cam_rep_20220120.csv > camrepnew.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone finds this useful, I figured a way. The $2 contained the time stamp to I've done the below to add the 4 zeros.

cat cam_rep_20220120.csv_20220120_test.csv | awk '{$2=".0000"; print $0}' > camrepnew.csv

This created the file with a space before ".0000" you can then remove that space by replacing it with below command

sed -i 's/ .0000 /.0000,/g' camrepnew.csv